# Excel formula help - date formula needed

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

Im hoping someone can help or advise.

I want a formula to count the number of days left in a month from the date of the first of that month. If that month has passed, I would like to it to stop at zero.

For ease, my image shows a yellow column, they are the answers.

When I wrote this, the date was 23rd july 2023, therefore in july there would have been be 9 days left in the month on that day.

Please help - thank you. [image: Date formula needed]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi Markus, To be hones 0 Im completely stumped on this one. 

I thought perhaps of doing an IF formula counting the difference from todays date and if the result was negative to stop at 0 but the outcomes were limitless with future dates.

Comment: I tried this which puts all zeros in, but doesn't work for Jul onwards - =IF(H2="","",MAX(0,(-TODAY())))

Answer (score 3):

Try the following formula:

```
=IF(MONTH(A7)=MONTH(TODAY()),B7-DAY(TODAY()),IF(MONTH(A7)>MONTH(TODAY()),B7,0))
```

It compares the current month with the month on column A. If there are the same, it calculates the number of days left. If not, it compares if the month in column A is greater than the current month. If yes, it display the number of days from column B. If the month is lower than the current month, `0` is shown.

Drag it up and down to fill the other cells. Adapt the formula to fit your range(s).

[image]

**Demo**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

=IF(TODAY()>EOMONTH(H2,0),0,IF(EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)<EOMONTH(H2,0),DAY(EOMONTH(H2,0)),IF(TODAY()>H2,DAY(EOMONTH(H2,0))-(DAY(TODAY())-1),DAY(EOMONTH(H2,0))-(DAY(H2)-1))))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).